# Stop conditional formatting on a saved spreadsheet after a certain date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a spreadsheet where I want to format dates that are coming up in the next week. The code works fine, but after the next week has passed, the formatting continues, I don't want that.  I only want the upcoming week from the day the file was generated to be formatted.  To clarify I'll give an example:

- upcoming week Oct 6 to Oct 12 format dates
- save file
- re-open file on Oct 13 and now upcoming week Oct 13 to Oct 19 is formatted

I want to open THIS SAVED SPREADSHEET at any point in time and only the week Oct 6 to Oct 12 is formatted. Here is the code I use, is there a command I can put in to stop formatting after the day the spreadsheet is generated?

```
    Macro1 Macro
    With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
    Cells.Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTimePeriod, DateOperator:=7
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .Color = -16711681
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-30
End Sub
```

Comment: If I understand your question, you could probably use a formula-based conditional format (just don't include TODAY in it, but hard-code the date).

Comment: Yes, formula based, something like so, mine is checking for 50+ before the end of September `=AND($H$2>=50,TODAY()<DATE(2019,9,30))`

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  I should I have added that this is a spreadsheet I generate every week, so the generated date is dynamic.  i.e this weeks file generation date is Nov 1 so I want Nov 3 to Nov 9 formatted Next weeks file generation date is Nov 7, so I only want Nov 10 to Nov 16 formatted.

Comment: Yes - but you can get today's date with `Date` in VBA. So you should be able to build up the formula to use.

Comment: OH, I see yes.  Let me give that a try and see what happens.  Thanks!